# Eclipse says "Launching : Verifying launch attributes", for half an hour, for a medium sized project

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat7

Fellow Developers on Eclipse, you should surely have encountered such a thing.

have a small POC, which just launches RESTful Webservice client on tomcat which has been already launched.

Eclipse shows, "Launching : Verifying launch attributes", like more than 30 minutes

Any directions or inputs highly appreciated.....

Comment: Sometimes I got simular problems, usually a restart fixes these problems. .

Comment: Tried what not, created new workspaces, new projects, just one project, to isolate the problem and yet still the issues are the only thing constant eating up a lot of time, inclusive of the restart suggestion...

Answer (score -1):

Maven version 3.6 seems to fix this problem.